# Find max value in a cell with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with Pandas like this:

Dataframe

[image: 1]

Now how can i find which day and which country have the most new covid case overall. Thanks

Country A -- 5309 case -- 12/12/2021
the answer should be like this

Comment: have you tried any code yet? Can you show us?

Comment: I have no ideal how to approach this problem so.